# Android send HTTP POST to trigger cloud functions with Retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, http, retrofit, google-cloud-functions

I've a cloud function that uses "context.auth.uid" and for JSON parsing reasons I want to trigger it by using Retrofit instead of Firebase functions API. But I'm getting this error when I try so: `Request has incorrect Content-Type. app/google-services.json`. And I don't know how to pass the Authentication information that function API passes.
So here are my codes:

***Cloud Functions HTTP Function:***

```
exports.getMatches = functions.https.onCall((req, context) => {

    var uid = context.auth.uid;
    console.log("uid: ", uid);
});
```

***Android SearchAPI Interface for Retrofit***

```
public interface ElasticSearchAPI
 {

    @POST("getMatches/")
    Call<ElasticHitsObject> getMatches(@Header("Content-Type") String 
    content_type,@Header("Authorization") String secretKey);

 }
```

***Android calling the function***

```
   Call<ElasticHitsObject> call = searchAPI.getMatches("app/google-services.json","api_key");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit doesn't know how to invoke [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), as you have declared in your code.  They have a [special protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) that's designed to be used with Firebase client SDK.

If you want to use an HTTP client library to invoke a Cloud Functions, you should make an [HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) instead, not a callable.  Note that they are declared differently. One starts with `functions.https.onCall()` and the other with `functions.https.onRequest()`.

Comment: That sounds like a different question to post on Stack Overflow.